# script does not run on invisible asp:Panel after making it visible (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp:Panel that I only make visible after a survey is completed. I have a script in the panel that displays a TripAdvisor widget. When the panel is made visible, the widget does not display. If I set the panel to visible when loading the survey, the widget does appear. How can I get the script to run after I make the panel visible? The asp:Panel code is below.

Thank you very much for any help.

```
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelReviewSite" runat="server" CssClass="Panel" Visible="false">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <div id="TA_sswidecollectreview991" class="TA_sswidecollectreview">
                            <ul id="8XReiUtFMK2" class="TA_links R9Huu5J0oLD">
                                <li id="6lsEHIwyG34" class="RywVDRO81a">Write a review of <a target="_blank" href="http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-......">My Hotel</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <script src="http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=sswidecollectreview&amp;uniq=991&amp;locationId=81234&amp;lang=en_US&amp;border=true"></script>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Comment: How do you change the visibility of your panel? On post back?

Comment: The script won't run just because the panel is now visible.  it just doesn't work that way.  Rather than trying  to execute the script by making the panel visible, I'm pretty sure you want to ececute the script based on a server-side event handler.  If so, see this post: http://www.aspforums.net/Threads/339520/Call-JavaScript-function-in-Server-side-ASPNet-Button-click-event/

Comment: Are you sure the following `class="TA_sswidecollectreview"`, `class="TA_links R9Huu5J0oLD"` and/or `class="RywVDRO81a"` does not contain css that set the `display:none` somewhere?

Comment: udidu - I just do Me.PanelReviewSite.Visible = True in a my vb codebehind off a button click. As I mentioned, if I set the panel to True by default, the widget shows fine. Thanks...sl.

Comment: Thanks David. I'll look at your link...sl.

Answer (score 0):

Add to panel additional css class with `display:none` property in definition instead of using `Visible` property. And reset CssClass property back to `Panel` on survey completion.

Comment: I think he'd want to use visibility: hidden.

Comment: visibility: hidden hides the element, but it still takes up space in the layout

Comment: Thank you very much Yuriy. That worked. I really appreciate your help...sl.

Comment: Spoke too soon. It works in debug, but not when I publish the aspx.